# In Objective-C, what is the best way to add NSIntegers together?

Tags: objective-c

This code works, hide the search bar if less than ten items, but I don't like the casts to int. Is there a better way to do it?

```
 if( kScreenFull > ((int)[[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:kReal] + (int)[[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:kIncome]) )
  [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0) animated:NO];
```

Comment: I accept that this answer is correct.

Comment: @user407341 click the hollow checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Ah Ha! now I got it! - you need to "tick the hollow check mark to the left of my answer." - In other words, on the left edge of this main page, just under the big number, look for the big-tick and toggle it to green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the casts to int. NSInteger is just a machine independent int.

In essence the only thing different about NSInteger is that on a 64bit system, it will be a long, not an int.

Comment: Thanks. Initially 2 + 2 == syntax/type/error; ...some time later... after some complicated successes with NSNumber I got it back down to (int)2 + (int)2 == 4; Phew! Now it seems that 2 + 2 == 4; so there is a god after all.